# Colorize string between to characters with lstdefinelanguage in latex

Tags: listings

I want to change the color of all method names to blue. Method are defined by a dot in front and an opening parenthesis after. Example:

```
.setLanguage("de");
```

Here i just want the *setLanguage* in another color. How can I do this?
I am currently just able to change the color of *setLanguage(*

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstdefinelanguage{Java}{
  sensitive = true,
  keywords={},
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
  % This is where i try it
  morecomment=[s][\color{blue}\bfseries]{.}{(},
  aboveskip=2em,
  belowskip=2em,
  sensitive=true
}

\lstset{
   backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
   extendedchars=true,
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
   showstringspaces=false,
   showspaces=false,
   numbers=left,
   numberstyle=\footnotesize,
   numbersep=7pt,
   tabsize=1,
   breaklines=true,
   showtabs=true,
   captionpos=b,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{small}
\lstinputlisting[language=Java]{test.java}
\end{small}
\caption{Service 1}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an elegant answer, but it works. Simply define another set of comments for content between `(` and `)` without any formatting.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{Java}{
    sensitive = true,
    keywords={},
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
    % This is where i try it
    moredelim=*[s][\color{blue}\bfseries]{.}{(},
    moredelim=*[s][]{(}{)}, % <-- additional setting
    aboveskip=2em,
    belowskip=2em,
    sensitive=true
}

\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbersep=7pt,
    tabsize=1,
    breaklines=true,
    showtabs=true,
    captionpos=b,
}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.java}
a.setLanguage("de");
b.hello("world");
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{small}
        \lstinputlisting[language=Java]{test.java}
    \end{small}
    \caption{Service 1}
\end{figure} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is actually a very simple and clean solution. Never thought about something like this. 
Thanks!